# Find a multiplier for two sets of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, nonlinear-optimization

I have two sets of $3 \times 3$ matrices $\left\{M_i\right\}_{i=1,n}$ and $\left\{U_j\right\}_{j=1,m}$. I want to find two vectors $x$ and $y$ such that for $i=1,\ldots,n, j=1,\ldots,m$, we have:

$$x.M_i.y<c<x.U_j.y$$

How do I proceed?
Thanks.

Comment: One can say "for $i=1,\ldots,n$" or "for all $i\in\{1,\ldots,n\},$" but "for all $i=1,\ldots,n$" is not correct usage. $\qquad$

Comment: Thanks @MichaelHardy. It is much clearer now!